# Sample n consecutive dates from a random starting date for each index in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
    DF = structure(list(c_number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), date = c("2001-01-06", "2001-01-07", "2001-01-08", 
"2001-01-09", "2001-01-10", "2001-01-11", "2001-01-12", "2001-01-13", 
"2001-01-14", "2001-01-15", "2001-01-16", "2001-01-17", "2001-01-18", 
"2001-01-19", "2001-01-20", "2001-01-21", "2001-01-22", "2001-01-23", 
"2001-01-24", "2001-01-25", "2001-01-26", "2001-01-11", "2001-01-12", 
"2001-01-13", "2001-01-14", "2001-01-15", "2001-01-16", "2001-01-17", 
"2001-01-18", "2001-01-19", "2001-01-20", "2001-01-21", "2001-01-22", 
"2001-01-23", "2001-01-24", "2001-01-25", "2001-01-26", "2001-01-27", 
"2001-01-28", "2001-01-12", "2001-01-13", "2001-01-14", "2001-01-15", 
"2001-01-16", "2001-01-17", "2001-01-18", "2001-01-19", "2001-01-20", 
"2001-01-21", "2001-01-22", "2001-01-23", "2001-01-24", "2001-01-25", 
"2001-01-26", "2001-01-27", "2001-01-28", "2001-01-29", "2001-01-30", 
"2001-01-21", "2001-01-22", "2001-01-23", "2001-01-24", "2001-01-25", 
"2001-01-26", "2001-01-27", "2001-01-28", "2001-01-29", "2001-01-30", 
"2001-01-31", "2001-01-24", "2001-01-25", "2001-01-26", "2001-01-27", 
"2001-01-28", "2001-01-29", "2001-01-30", "2001-01-31", "2001-02-01"
), value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("c_number", 
"date", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -78L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have sales data for 5 customer on consecutive dates; For customer 1, I have sales data on 21 consecutive dates....for customer # 5, I have sales data on 9 consecutive dates...:

```
> table(DF[, 1])

 1  2  3  4  5 
21 18 19 11  9
```

For each customer I want to sample a sub DF of 15 consecutive days (If I have at least 15 consecutive dates for that customer) or all dates for that customer (if I don't have  15 consecutive dates for that customer).

The key part is that in case 1 (If I have at least 15 consecutive dates for that customer) those 15 consecutive days should have a random start date (e.g. not always be the first or last 15 dates for an customer) to avoid introducing a bias in the analysis.

In plain R I would do:

```
library(dplyr)

slow_function <- function(i, DF, length_out = 15){
  sub_DF = DF[DF$c_number == i, ]
  if(nrow(sub_DF) <= length_out){
    out_DF = sub_DF
  } else {
    random_start = sample.int(nrow(sub_DF) - length_out, 1)
    out_DF = sub_DF[random_start:(random_start + length_out - 1), ]
  }
}
a_out = lapply(1:nrow(a_1), slow_function, DF = DF, length_out = 15)
a_out = dplyr::bind_rows(a_out)


table(a_out[, 1])
 1  2  3  4  5 
15 15 15 11  9
```

But my data is much larger and the operation above unbearably slow. Is there a fast way to obtain the same result in data.table/dplyr?

## Edit: code to generate the data.

```
num_customer = 10
m   = 2 * num_customer
a_0 = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2001-12-31"), by = "day")
a_1 = matrix(sort(sample(as.character(a_0), m)), nc = 2)
a_2 = list()
for(i in 1:nrow(a_1)){
  a_3 = seq(as.Date(a_1[i, 1]), as.Date(a_1[i, 2]), by = "day")
  a_4 = data.frame(i, as.character(a_3), round(runif(length(a_3), 1)))
  colnames(a_4) = c("c_number", "date", "value")
  a_2[[i]] = a_4
}
DF = dplyr::bind_rows(a_2)
dim(DF)
table(DF[, 1])
dput(DF)
```

## Edit2:

on a 100k customer DF, Christoph Wolk's solution is the fastest. 
Next is G. Grothendieck's (about 4 times more time), next is 
Nathan Werth's (another factor of 2 slower than G. Grothendieck's). 
The other solutions are noticeably slower. Still, all proposals are faster than my tentative 'slow_function' so thanks to everyone!

Comment: Question is a little unclear. For each employee, you want to choose a random starting date and sample a maximum of 15 consecutive days after that starting point? Or, if the random choice would result in less than 15 data points for the employee, just take the last 15?

Comment: @jdobres: thanks for asking. Actually the second interpretation ('if the random choice would result in less than 15 data points for the employee, just take the last 15?') is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sample15consecutive <- function(DF) {
runs <- rle(DF$c_number)$lengths
start <- ifelse(runs > 15, sapply(pmax(runs-15, 1), sample.int, size=1), 1)
end <- ifelse(runs >= 15, 15, runs)
previous <- cumsum(c(0, head(runs, -1)))
DF[unlist(mapply(seq, previous + start, previous + start + end - 1), length),]
}
```

It's about 4 times faster according to microbenchmark. The c_numbers and dates have to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks (+1)! But wouldn't G. Grothendieck's answer be faster (much less overheads as he calls fewer O(n) functions)?

Comment: I can't say. In my microbenchmark, my version seems a little faster, but I might have made a mistake, or the behavior might depend on the specifics of the data - on the sample dataset all method are really fast. You could test it on your large data set.

Comment: Indeed, I tried again and I get a 4 times improvement on a larger data set. Thanks again for pointing the perf out!

Answer (score 2):

A way to speed up in base R might be to just work with indices rather than the whole data.frame before subsetting.

```
output = DF[unlist(lapply(
            split(1:NROW(DF), DF$c_number),  #Split indices along rows of DF
            function(x){
                if(length(x) < 15){          #Grab all indices if there are less than 15
                    x
                } else{
                    #Grab an index randomly such that there will be 14 more left after it
                    x[sample(0:(length(x) - 15), 1) + sequence(15)]
                }
            })),
            ]

sapply(split(output, output$c_number), NROW)
# 1  2  3  4  5 
#15 15 15 11  9
```

Comment: How is this using data.table/dplyr to speed things up? Or do you mean this problem can't be sped up using data.table/dplyr?

Comment: `lapply` is more or less a wrapper for a standard R loop, which is slow. The dplyr and data.table packages utilize a lot of faster C code to speed up basic operations.

Comment: @jdobres - `lapply` uses a C loop.  The last line of the `lapply` source shows it being dispatched into the internal C code. `.Internal(lapply(X, FUN))` It is not slow when used properly.

Comment: @RichScriven Huh. Didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that about lapply either. I find G. Grothendieck's answer a bit more intuitive (but this is subjective), but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward with the **tidyverse** packages (specifically, **dplyr** and **tidyr**).

```
library(tidyverse)

df.sample <- arrange(DF, date) %>% 
  group_by(c_number) %>% 
  do(head(., 15))
```

Output (first 30 rows / 2 employees):

```
# A tibble: 65 x 3
   c_number       date value
      <int>      <chr> <dbl>
 1        1 2001-01-06     1
 2        1 2001-01-07     1
 3        1 2001-01-08     1
 4        1 2001-01-09     1
 5        1 2001-01-10     1
 6        1 2001-01-11     1
 7        1 2001-01-12     1
 8        1 2001-01-13     1
 9        1 2001-01-14     1
10        1 2001-01-15     1
11        1 2001-01-16     1
12        1 2001-01-17     1
13        1 2001-01-18     1
14        1 2001-01-19     1
15        1 2001-01-20     1
16        2 2001-01-11     1
17        2 2001-01-12     1
18        2 2001-01-13     1
19        2 2001-01-14     1
20        2 2001-01-15     1
21        2 2001-01-16     1
22        2 2001-01-17     1
23        2 2001-01-18     1
24        2 2001-01-19     1
25        2 2001-01-20     1
26        2 2001-01-21     1
27        2 2001-01-22     1
28        2 2001-01-23     1
29        2 2001-01-24     1
30        2 2001-01-25     1
# ... with 35 more rows
```

## Edit: the following selects a random start date for each employee and then selects up to 15 consecutive days after the randomly chosen point:

```
df.sample <- arrange(DF, date) %>% 
  group_by(c_number) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date), start = sample(date, 1)) %>% 
  filter(date >= start & date <= (start + 14))
```

Comment: Not the same, because you alway take the last 15 rows for each customer. But I want 30 consecutive rows from a random start date. I reworded the title to make this more clear (mea maxima culpa)

Comment: Updated to better match your intent. Can't guarantee that it's the fastest, but it's very readable.

Comment: this (after the edit) is exactly the answer to my question (+1). But d.b and G. Grothendieck's answers are showing I was not asking the correct question.

Answer (score 1):

`samp` generates a vector of 1 (in sample) and 0 (out of sample) and we subset by that.  I haven't benchmarked it but it does not break up `DF` into sub-dataframes but only splits the `c_number` vector and then does a single subset on the original `DF`.

```
samp <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  replace(0*x, seq(sample(max(n - 15, 1), 1), length = min(n, 15)), 1)
}
s <- subset(DF, ave(c_number, c_number, FUN = samp) == 1)
```

Comment: That is super clever. Please let me a couple of minutes to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DF)

DF[
  ,
  {
    if (.N <= 15) {
      # 15 or fewer rows? Grab them all.
      .SD
    } else {
      # Grab a random starting row not too close to the end
      random_start <- sample(seq_len(.N - 14), size = 1)
      .SD[random_start + 0:14]
    }
  },
  by = c_number
]
```

Comment: this is exactly the answer to my question (+1). But d.b and G. Grothendieck's answers are showing I was not asking the correct question.